# Angular 2 is throwing and error if I don't have .js in my import statements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I followed the directions from angular.io's 5 minute quickstart and everything worked fine.  I didn't have to declare .js when I used

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

I then started using templateUrl to load in other components

```
import {NavMenuComponent} from '../nav/navMenu';
@Component ({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    directives: [NavMenuComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

When I run the code I get an error saying it could not find localhost:300/src/nav/navMenu

BUT if I add a .js to the end

```
 import {NavMenuComponent} from '../nav/navMenu.js';
```

it works fine.  I have the index.html already set to..

```
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Shouldn't that make it so I don't have to use the .js extension on imports anymore?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either change your package in the system config or change the `src` folder for `app`

Comment: @Langley, I do not follow.  The angular.io doesn't have a system config file.  Can you be more specific on the fix please.

Comment: not `config.js` file, the `System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {` part you have in your code.

Comment: Your `System.config` is specifying to use a default extension of `js` on stuff under the `app` package, but for what I see, your component is under `src` not `app` : `localhost:300/src/nav/navMenu` does that make sense?

Comment: I think I do.  so I have to change app to src or create one that says src with a defaultExtension?  Is that correct?

Comment: Something like System.config({ packages: { src: { defaultExtension: 'js' } } });

Answer (score 0):

The solution was exactly what @Langely posted above.  Once I added the necessary folders it all worked.  In the end I moved it all under one umbrella that handled everything.

```
app
-- controllers
    -- file.ts
```